# Django form save or model save with a select field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I'm still new to Django. I have a single field in my form. And I was just wondering whether or not I need a form save function or a model save function? When is it appropriate to use either or?

For instance: My form:

```
class OpinionStatusForm(forms.Form):
    choices = (('0', "Your Status"), ('1', "This"), ('2', "That"), ('3', "The Other"))
    status = forms.CharField(max_length=2, widget=forms.Select(choices=choices, attrs={'class':'status_dropdown','onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}), required=False)

    def save(self, opinion_status):
        opinion_status.status = self.cleaned_data['status']
```

My model:

```
class OptionStatus(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=opinion_statuses)
    opinion = models.ForeignKey(Opinion, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OpinionStatus, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm going to be ajax-ing the form. I don't know if that makes a difference or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually need, is a ModelForm. In your example you're working with a standard forms.Form. This is not bound to a model instance. As a result, there's also no need for a save method. The best examples are really given inside the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Go step by step over the code examples and you'll understand. It would be too much to explain it all in one Stackoverflow answer - and the Django docs are incredible thorough.